# populate UITableView with data stored in Firebase database

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a UITableVIew in my iPhone application that populates each cell using an array but the question is how do you populate the array with values retrieved from the firebase database:

```
func retData(){
    rootRef.child("users").child("Test").observeEventType(.Value){
        (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    }
}

 var no1 = ["3","6","3","4","5","20","34","34"]
```

Table Code:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath     
 indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let cell1 = self.h_table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1",    
 forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Hole_Cell

    cell1.s_label.text = usersArray[indexPath.row]
```

firebase data Structure:

```
 --Users
       --Test: 1
       --Test1: 2
       --Test2: 3
       --Test4: 4
```

Comment: Can you show us how your data is structured in firebase?

Comment: updated the question containing the data structure

Comment: Recommended: https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd or https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var usersArray: [String]?

func retData() {
    rootRef.child("users").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in


        usersArray = [String]()
        for user in snapshot.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
          let userString = user.value as? String
          usersArray?.append(userString!)
        }

    })
}
```

***Edit Try this:

```
var usersArray = [String]()

func retData() {
    rootRef.child("users").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let usersDict = snapshot.value as! [String:String]
        self.usersArray= Array(usersDict.values)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
       }

    })
}
```

*** Again Edit: Add this within the closure to account for when users has no data.

```
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
          return
        } else {
           let usersDict = snapshot.value as! [String:String]
           self.usersArray= Array(usersDict.values)
           self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: it flags an error 'value type 'FIRDataSnapshot' has no member 'allObjects'

Comment: @crispy2k12 try the new solution I proposed above.

Comment: i have the error index out of range, is they a way to specific how many values will be in the array

Comment: @crispy2k12 check that the dictionary is not empty. After creating usersDict add this line: print("Dictionary: \(usersDict)")

Comment: it appears to be empty, i'm getting this error "Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10eaf2378) to 'NSString' (0x10eee2b20)."

Comment: @crispy2k12 It looks like "users" in my code above is lowercase but you have "Users" in your data structure.

Comment: @crispy2k12 hmm. For some reason you are pulling no data. Make sure you have data at the users node. From your data above it appears that you do. I also updated my answer to account for when users has no data.

Comment: I've updated my question with sections of the UITableView code, if this helps in anyway

Answer (score 0):

Check my latest Questions, basically the same stuff. Checkout [Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS), very useful.

I used a ViewController with a table view and a Prototype Cell in it. Then this worked for me:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabaseUI

class LinksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

var dataSource: FirebaseTableViewDataSource?
var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource.init(query: myQuery(),prototypeReuseIdentifier: "<Your-Identifier>", view: self.tableView)

dataSource?.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in

//Populate your Cell here
}
       tableView.dataSource = dataSource
       tableView.delegate = self


 }
  }
```

Note that the `myQuery` is basically then your first line.